# I get an error when writing a 1 dimension array to a single column

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
Sub Lottery()
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim D As Long
Dim E As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim xLot() As String

N = 0
ReDim xLot(1 To 169911)
For A = 1 To 27
    For B = A + 1 To 28
        For C = B + 1 To 29
            For D = C + 1 To 30
                For E = D + 1 To 31
                    N = N + 1

                    xLot(N) = A & "-" & B & "-" & C & "-" & D & "-" & E
                    'Debug.Print xLot(N), N
                    'Range("a" & N).Value = xLot(N)

                Next E
            Next D
        Next C
    Next B
Next A

Range("A1:A169911").Resize(169911, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xLot)

End Sub
```

using transpose Run time error 13 Type mismatch.  I read in a different blog that I cannot write to more than 65535 cells.  In another instance, after row 38840 to 169911 (number of combinations) the cells have #N/A.  I have run it in the immediate window and the array account for all combinations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You cant use the transpose function for more than 65535 values because transpose converts a range of columns into a range of rows (and vice versa), and there can only be 65535 columns in an excel worksheet. You could bypass the transpose function by giving the array a second dimension, so change the redim statement to:

```
ReDim xLot(1 To 169911,0)
```

and your assignment statement to:

```
xLot(N,0) = A & "-" & B & "-" & C & "-" & D & "-" & E
```

...and finally your range statement to:

```
Range("A1:A169911").Resize(169911, 1).Value = xLot
```

Edit: Just tested it, this code worked for me:

```
Sub Lottery()
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    Dim D As Long
    Dim E As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim xLot() As String

    N = 0
    ReDim xLot(1 To 169911, 0)
    For A = 1 To 27
        For B = A + 1 To 28
            For C = B + 1 To 29
                For D = C + 1 To 30
                    For E = D + 1 To 31
                        N = N + 1

                        xLot(N, 0) = A & "-" & B & "-" & C & "-" & D & "-" & E
                        'Debug.Print xLot(N), N
                        'Range("a" & N).Value = xLot(N)

                    Next E
                Next D
            Next C
        Next B
    Next A

    Range("A1:A169911").Resize(169911, 1).Value = xLot
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe make that 2nd dimension 1-based, like the first?

Comment: You can if you like, but its bad practice generally to start an array anywhere but 0. In VBA, it *slightly* increases the memory overhead. I don't have any data on if this would apply to each element of an array, so i'd prefer not to tempt fate by using a lbound of 1 when there are 6-figure numbers in play. Not that it would matter anyway, this code runs in microseconds.

Comment: agreed on using base 0 when you can, but *mixing* bases is worse than using base 1, IMO. Might be better to make them both base 0.

Comment: Mixing bases is no issue for the compiler, the more base 0, the lower the overhead, but i agree, its *terrible* general practice, but I also didn't want to change his code that dramatically. I don't want to sound patronising with "let me just change the semantics of what you've written with properly formed code (imho)"

Comment: agreed. no issue for the compiler, but issue for the code maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

Transpose has an upper limit of about 65k items.

If you instead

```
ReDim xLot(1 To 169911, 1 to 1) 
'....
xLot(N, 1) = A & "-" & B & "-" & C & "-" & D & "-" & E
'...
```

then you won't need to Transpose:

```
Range("A1:A169911").Value = xLot
```

Comment: I have adjusted my code to reflect the changes suggested, now I get a "script out of range" , I would expect that it now wants a 2nd dimension for the ReDim xLot(1 To 169911, 1 To 1).  I have run it writing directly to the sheet, but it takes about 7 min. on my machine.

Comment: The code i wrote in my answer above should take less than a couple of seconds to run, I don't know why it would take 7 minutes, have you tried copy/pasting it across? Also, could you mark one of these answers as "answered" please?